# What is the difference between below two Network Extension option in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, networkextension

I am trying to find the working on NetworkExtension framework but as explained in the apple documentation I couldn't understand and decide which option should I choose.

> First option showed in the picture provides:

`App Proxy,`
`Packet Tunnel,`
`Filter Data,`
`Filter Packet,`
`DNS Proxy`

> Second option showed in the picture provides:

`App Proxy,`
`Packet Tunnel`

Can anyone explain in details about the usage of all these options.

Please help
Thank you

[image: System Extension->Network Extension]
[image: Application Extension->Network Extension]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a difference until [the recent update](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67613). The former needs a special entitlement to distribute and supports macOS before 10.15; the latter allows one to use Developer ID to distribute and requires macOS 10.15.